# Imprimir Mayor Subserie Creciente En Un Array

Tags: java, array

He conseguido sin problemas generar un array de tamaño 30 con números aleatorios dentro de un cierto rango (en mi caso de 1 a 100) con Math.random. Pero ahora tengo que, del array obtenido extraer la mayor subserie creciente que haya e imprimirla.

---

Ejemplo:
Mi vector es:
2 3 4 2 4 8 9 1 1 8 2 9 2 0 88 2 81 22 12 22 **8 9 10 23 38 49** 22 33 1 98

Por lo que la subserie creciente mayor a imprimir es:
**8 9 10 23 38 49**

El código que llevo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //CREO UN ARRAY DE TAMAÑO 30
        int [] serie= new int [30];

        //ESTA LÍNEA ES SÓLO POR ESTÉTICA, ADORNA EL VECTOR GENERADO.
        System.out.print("Vector: ");

        //CREO UN BUCLE PARA RELLENAR POSICIONES CON NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS E IMPRIMIR EL ARRAY.
        for (int i=0;i<=29;i++){
            serie[i]= (int)(Math.random()*100-1)+1;
            System.out.print("|"+serie[i]);
        }

        //ESTA LÍNEA ES SÓLO POR ESTÉTICA, CIERRA EL CASILLERO DEL ÚLTIMO NÚMERO.
        System.out.print("|");
    }
```

¡Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego código comentado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //CREO UN ARRAY DE TAMAÑO 30
    int[] serie = new int[30];

    //ESTA LÍNEA ES SÓLO POR ESTÉTICA, ADORNA EL VECTOR GENERADO.
    System.out.print("Vector: ");

    //CREO UN BUCLE PARA RELLENAR POSICIONES CON NÚMEROS ALEATORIOS E IMPRIMIR EL ARRAY.
    for (int i = 0; i <= 29; i++) {
        serie[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 - 1) + 1;
        System.out.print("|" + serie[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("|");

    // variables para registrar la sub serie actual
    int i;
    int j = 0;

    // variables para registrar la sub serie más grande
    int inicio = 0;
    int fin = 0;

    // se empieza en 1 para comparar con el elemento anterior
    for (i = 1; i < serie.length; i++) {

        if (serie[i] > serie[i - 1]) continue;

        // si la serie entre j e i - 1  es mayor que la serie entre
        // fin - inicio, guardar la serie actual como la más grande
        if ((i - 1) - j > fin - inicio) {
            inicio = j;
            fin = i - 1;
        }
        // mover el inicio de la próxima serie
        j = i;

    }
    // imprimir la serie
    for (int k = inicio; k <= fin; k++) {
        System.out.print(serie[k] + " ");
    }

}
```